# How to maintain the checkbox state in the header rows across the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, state

I know how to keep track of the checkbox in a datarow, but I got no idea on keep tracking the checkbox state in the header rows.

For example, assume my gridview have 3 pages, after I check the checkbox in the header rows in 1st page, I click on 2nd or 3rd pages, and click back to my 1st page, my checkbox status in 1st page still remains checked. 
What's the solution for it? Sample codes provided is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer at [Gridview: Maintain selected checkbox state while Paging](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/883833-gridview-maintain-selected-checkbox-state-while-paging)

> You need to keep track of what has
>   been selected. You essentially want to
>   keep track of the unique IDs for each
>   row that has been selected. Please
>   remember that you can Sort a GridView
>   and so you can't just keep track of
>   the indexes...you should use some sort
>   of unique identify for each row.
>
> You will need to store this somewhere.
>   You could store the selected unique
>   IDs in Session, ViewState,
>   Cookies....a HiddenField...whatever
>   you fancy so long as it is accessible
>   between postbacks.
>
> Every time the user postsback to the
>   server you should update your list of
>   selected unique IDs so that you are
>   always current.
>
> That's pretty much it.

This link might be usefull too 
[Maintaining States of Selected CheckBoxes in Different Pages inside the GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/States_of_CheckBoxes.aspx)

Comment: thanks hansmukh...but i guess the checkbox in header row doesn't have a unique id right?

Comment: yes, other wise it will be bit difficult for you. do check out second link. and dont forget to mark this as answer if this helps =)

Comment: Verbatim copy of http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/883833-gridview-maintain-selected-checkbox-state-while-paging